# AVFoundation camera view shrinking when status bar appears

Tags: ios, swift, view, camera, avfoundation

I am using AVFoundation to show a live preview of the camera view (back) at high resolution. But when I am in a call, or sharing internet, or however a status bar appears, the preview shrinks despite the layer being bound to the view container. Images:

https://m.imgur.com/2gElGb6,XhQTrum

That is the comparison. Would anyone know why?

EDIT: I am aware of the default movement: Application is moved down. This is NOT what I am referring to. The view itself is distorted as viewable in the screenshots.

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen. Look at any app you care to name: when the in-call status bar appears, the app moves down.

Comment: @matt It's not the fact that it moves down.. It's the fact that the view itself shrinks. Check the screenshots to see what I mean.